# How to remove special characters from XML stored in ADLS using Azure data factory or any other option?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, custom-activity

I have scenario where i need to remove some characters from xml tags which is stored in ADLS. I am looking for an option with ADF. Can someone help me here with approach i should follow?

Answer (score 0):

> This is not possible by ADF. May you can have piece code to do this in
> Azure Functions. As, Azure Data Factory can do data movement and data
> transformation only. When you are saying about tags that means it does
> not come under that.

You may use the Azure Function activity in a Data Factory pipeline to run Azure Functions. To launch an Azure Function, you must first set up a connected service connection and an activity that specifies the Azure Function you want to perform.

There is the Microsoft document which have deep insights about Azure Function Activity in ADF | [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity).